# Determining the first and last point that a polygon intersects

Tags: qgis, vector, intersection

I have this...

[image]

And I want to join those attributes to the polygon automatically:
[image]

Because I'll have to replicate this on tones of those polygons.

If this works I would like to know if it still works for non-intersections.

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE. Please make sure to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) which provides some guidelines on Q&A in the forum. Regarding this thread, If you could clarify what you are asking, maybe add an image of your layers, with marks on these first & last intersections.

Comment: the length of a polygon is just its perimeter, and there's an expression in QGIS for that.

Comment: not its perimeter or its width, i want the length